# Is navigator.buildID unique for each visitor?

Tags: javascript

Is `navigator.buildID` unique for each visitor (I want to use it to keep track on visitors)?

If yes, is there something simliar in Chrome, Safari and IE?

Comment: Don't forget to ask your users if you can track them, and also implement http://donottrack.us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is navigator.buildID unique for each visitor

No, [it's the build number of the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.buildID), specifically Gecko browsers (like Firefox). It's used to identify the version of the browser, thus not making it unique at all.

> I want to use it to keep track on visitors

If you want to keep track of users, you can use other mechanisms, like requiring registration, cookies, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So the "build number of the browser" will be the same for each visitor that has the same version of Firefox? It's not the time when the browser was updated (wich could work as a identifier)? What are the four last numbers (YYYY MM DD HH XXXX)?

Comment: @user1087110 "So the "build number of the browser" will be the same for each visitor that has the same version of Firefox?" Yes. "What are the four last numbers" I would suppose mmss (minutes, seconds) and the documentation is out of date. Verifying...